# linked server errror with semaphore error

Tags: sql, sql-server, admin, administration, database-administration

I received below error from the application user that they are getting below error frequently from yesterday. but in the errorlog of the sql server doesn`t have any such error. One error which I can relate to this is **DBCC MEMORYSTATUS** generated error in the errorlog **Failed Virtual Allocate Bytes: FAIL_VIRTUAL_RESERVE 1048576** . The reason behind relating this message to the below error is the time at which both occurred . During same time transaction log was also being backed up.

Ram of the server is 16G.

Can you please help me after reading the below error log.

**Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired. [SQLSTATE 07008] (Error 121)  Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 65535)  Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 65535)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.1.1" returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.157.12" returned message "Communication link failure". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.1.1" returned message "Communication link failure". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "192.168.1.1" returned message "Communication link failure". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.**

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar